# how i get the value of a post variable, send by ajax in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

i send with ajax a id to a php side. The php side should answer with a MySql row with this ID.

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
dataType : 'jsonp',
type: "POST",
async: false,
traditional: true,
jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
contentType: "application/json",
data : {
'ID' : '2'
},
url : 'http://myside.de/sqlExecute.php',
success : function(sqlArray) {
console.log("Eingange " +sqlArray.ID);
console.log("Eingange " +sqlArray.Name);
},
error: function(a){
alert("error");
}

});
```

php:

```
<?php
include('DatabaseConnector.php');
$array = toString('SELECT * FROM `RMap` WHERE `ID` ='+$_POST["ID"]);
$json = json_encode($array);
print $_GET['callback'] . "(" . $json . ")"
?>
```

this works:

```
<?php
include('DatabaseConnector.php');
$array = toString('SELECT * FROM `RMap` WHERE `ID` =2');
$json = json_encode($array);
print $_GET['callback'] . "(" . $json . ")"
?>
```

what is wrong on the $_Post variant?

Thanks

### UPDATE

Now i get the error message "200 Error: jsonCallback was not called", with this code:

```
 <?php
 include('DatabaseConnector.php');
 $array = toString('SELECT * FROM `RMap` WHERE `ID` ='.$_POST["ID"]);
 $json = json_encode($array);
 print $_GET['callback'] . "(" . $json . ")"
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like

```
$array = toString('SELECT * FROM `RMap` WHERE `ID` =' . $_POST["ID"]);
```

In **php** you `concat` with `.` and in **javascript** you do with `+`

Answer (score 1):

Use dot (.) for concatenation, instead of +

```
$array = toString('SELECT * FROM `RMap` WHERE `ID` ='.$_POST["ID"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT * FROM `RMap` WHERE `ID` ='+$_POST["ID"]
```

In PHP, you [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) strings with a `.` (dot) instead of a `+` (plus sign).

i.e. Your code should look like:

```
$array = toString('SELECT * FROM `RMap` WHERE `ID` =' . $_POST["ID"]);
```

Comment: 200 Error: jsonCallback was not called

Answer (score 0):

When you send data by ajax check in `firebug console` : Response you will get `ID` is `Undefined`.

If `ID` is undefined then how your query will works ?

So first of all need to solve that undefined error and then check your query.